# file corruption on SD card after PC 'disk drive' access

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard

I am having a problem with SD card file corruption in my app (which only opens the file for read anyway). It happens in one specific circumstance:
 - the app has been running, and has loaded data from the file (and closed it again)
 - the app has NOT been 'force closed'
 - the phone is connect to PC with SD card as a drive
 - various PC-phone file manipulation has gone on (but nothing with this specific file)
 - phone disconnected from PC
 - next time the app is run, the file will be corrupted and will not load correctly
 - there is no pattern to the corruption - random rubbish - but the file length is never changed

The code for reading the file is below, note - much simplified, all sorts of try/catch/other tests to check for problems along the way, and works fine except as detailed above. The file is raw binary, not text.

```
String  fullPath = " ... this will have the path to the file in it  ... ";
FileInputStream
            fs = new FileInputStream(fullPath);
DataInputStream
        ds = new DataInputStream(fs);

Boolean     res = loadBEBin(ds);    //  this reads and loads the file

fs.close();
return res;
```

Confused, any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be the case that with my pone (HTC Desire), if it is connected to a PC as a disk drive, and if Eclipse has been running during that log in session, everything just gets corrupted. Nothing specifically to do with my app.

Something to do with adb being loaded, I think.